# Need to refresh autocomplete json of another page from entry page in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

Created autocomplete json runtime from database for city list using jquery below code.
Autocomplete works fine but if i added any new city then autocomplete json is not refreshed until page load. If page loaded then newly added city found in list.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var data = [
                { "label": "Harry potter", "actor": "Books" },
                { "label": "Harry potter", "actor": "Films" },
                { "label": "King Lear", "actor": "Books" },
                { "label": "Alchemist", "actor": "Books" },
                { "label": "Avatar", "actor": "Films" },
                { "label": "Terminator", "actor": "Films" },
        ];

        $("#search").autocomplete(
                {
                    source: data,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#search").val(ui.item.label + " / " + ui.item.actor);
                        return false;
                    }
                }).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $("<li></li>")
                        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                        .append("<a><strong>" + item.label + "</strong> in " + item.actor + "</a>")
                        .appendTo(ul);
                };

    });

</script>
```

Please help me.

Comment: You dont have the city key in your JSON variable `data`

Comment: I had created JSON like this:                                                                   
     var data = [
                { "label": "Mumbai", "actor": "Maharashtra" },
                { "label": "Pune", "actor": "Maharashtra" },
                { "label": "Jaipur", "actor": "Rajasthan" },
                { "label": "Kolkata", "actor": "West Bengal" },
                { "label": "Surat", "actor": "Gujrat" }
               
        ];

Comment: You should load the JSON from the server side using `$.ajax()` in `jQuery` else if you declare the JSON from a variable in your script in the client side you have to manually refresh the `DOM` using `Ctrl + F5` event in Google Chrome.